# Working with static text data on iPhone

Tags: ios

So,

I have a large set of static text that I will be using over and over again in the app such as postcodes, suburb names and etc which will get occasionally downloaded. To ease the need to download data whenever I need it, I'm downloading all the data and saving it locally in a plist format which is around 3MB size. I'm now thinking of a better way to handle that. So, I'm just wondering what would be the best way to handle large data in my case.

For plist, I have a static class which loads all the data into array for example,

```
+(instanceof) sharedInstance {
     .....
     self.myarray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:PLISTPATH(@"suburbs.plist")]
     .....
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: it's a specific data or generic data for all app?

Comment: It's generic data for all your apps.

Comment: "better" is a vague description for what you want to achieve. What actual problem are you facing? Are you looking for performance, code quality, or memory footprint? What is your concern and why do you think your current approach needs refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest as 3 MB file when load with tons of objects every time it make your app very poor performing and might get killed by iOS, you should create a sqlite database for all this info and load the specific data based on ids.